# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oledb

I have two Tables:

1)  Products: (productID pk; productName; productDesc; catID fk; serial; unitPrice; reOrderLevel;)

2)  Transactions: (transID pk; trasDate; productID fk; purOrderID “purchase Order”; transDesc; unitsOrdered; unitsReceived;)

In the vb.net Form (Purchase Orders) I need to show within a form Datagridview, all the products ordered by the selected Purchase Order.

So I have done the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT     transactions.transDate,
     products.productName,     
     transactions.unitsOrdered, 
     products.unitPrice
FROM         products INNER JOIN
     transactions ON products.productID =  transactions.ProductID
WHERE     (transactions.purOrderID = ?)
```

Of course the purchase order should be passed as parameter, and will be get from the textbox “txtOrderID”

I have a button “Order Details” that should show the Products purchased by single order which have the following Codes:

```
      Me.DADetails.Fill(Me.DsDetails)

      Me.DADetails.SelectCommand.Parameters(0).Value = Me.txtOrderID.Text
```

When I run it and press on the Button Order Details I get the following error that point to the first line of code:

Title: OleDbException was unhandled

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'.
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Notice that, I have used the same way, the same code, the same Idea in other Forms and worked with no problem at all..

Comment: I am going to guess that something somwhere has the text `Default` which is a keyword or is maybe in `txtOrderID.Text`.  Hold your mouse over the SQL statement after it is built to see where it is coming from.

Comment: Dear Sir
there is no Keyword used neither in the database nor in the vb.net project
the SQL statement is correct
when I run it in the SQL builder: It works and returns the Result
I'm having headache Sir

Comment: *First* assign the parameter value and *then* run the `.Fill` method. Switch order of those 2 lines of code

Comment: Thank you Sir Yuriy
That worked :)
I hope u set ur solution as answer so that I can Check it :)

Comment: Will do, thanks :) glad it worked for u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happens because parameter is not set when the query runs.

*First* assign the parameter value and *then* run the `.Fill` method. Switch order of those 2 lines of code